# Retrieving data from a table in a database and displaying it on a Bootstrap card

Tags: php, laravel, view, localhost, bootstrap-5

Basically I am trying to retrieve data stored in a table in phpmyadmin and trying to display it on a Bootstrap card using foreach loops.

Here is what I have tried so far.

Here is the code for the route file **web.php**
`Route::get('/rewardsprograms', 'rewardsprogramController@index');`

And here is the code from the RewardsprogramController

```
public function index()
    {
        // $rewardAdd = rewardsprogram::all();
        // return view('reward_manage', compact('rewardAdd'));
        $rewardsprograms = rewardsprogram::all();
        return view('reward_manage', compact('rewardsprograms'));
    }
```

And here is the code from the view file reward_manage.blade.php

```
@foreach($rewardsprograms as $rewardsprogram)
<div class="container my-5 d-flex">
    <div class="card p-2 mx-5" style="width: 28rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title fw-bold text-dark">Rewards program name: {{ $rewardsprogram->$reward_program_name }} </h5>
            <h5 class="card-title fw-bold text-dark">Rewards program ID: {{ $rewardsprogram->$reward_program_ID }}</h5>
            <h5 class="card-title fw-bold text-dark">Description: {{ $rewardsprogram->$description }}</h5>
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary fw-bold btn-block">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary fw-bold btn-block">Delete rewards program</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

The name of the table the data is being stored is **rewardsprograms** and the name of the model is **rewardsprogram**.

Now I am new to Laravel and am getting the error **'Undefined variable $rewardsprograms'** and am stuck.

### Update

Never mind, I fixed the issue. I changed the route code to

```
Route::get('/rewardsprograms', [rewardsprogramController::class, 'index']);
```

And in the card I removed the $ sign in front of the table column names, so for example it's not:

```
$rewardsprogram->$reward_program_name
```

but:

```
$rewardsprogram->reward_program_name
```

Comment: So you fixed it, right?

Answer (score 0):

you should remove $ before the property name:

```php
@foreach($rewardsprograms as $rewardsprogram)
<div class="container my-5 d-flex">
    <div class="card p-2 mx-5" style="width: 28rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title fw-bold text-dark">Rewards program name: {{ $rewardsprogram->reward_program_name }} </h5>
            <h5 class="card-title fw-bold text-dark">Rewards program ID: {{ $rewardsprogram->reward_program_ID }}</h5>
            <h5 class="card-title fw-bold text-dark">Description: {{ $rewardsprogram->description }}</h5>
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary fw-bold btn-block">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary fw-bold btn-block">Delete rewards program</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).